# How to compare if two objects are really the same object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to compare if an variable A represents the same object as variable B does.

Could I do that with the == operator?

Or what else is this exactly looking at? I think I need to check for the memory adress of the object where the variable is pointing to, right?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `==` operator tests whether the two expressions are the same pointer to the same object. Cocoa calls this relation “identical” (see, for example, NSArray's `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`).

To test whether two objects are equal, you would send one of them an `isEqual:` message (or a more specific message, such as `isEqualToString:`, if it responds to one), passing the other object. This would return `YES` if you really only have one object (equal to itself, obviously) or if you have two objects that are equal. In the latter case, `==` will evaluate to `NO`.

Comment: So that isEqual method will check all instance variables and/or properties of the object and compare them with another? Or does it only compare the -hash values of NSObject. The -hash value is updated every time a property changes?

Comment: `isEqual:` and `hash` are both intended to be overridden. NSObject's implementation is pretty dumb: IIRC, `-[NSObject isEqual:]` tests pointer equality and `-[NSObject hash]` just returns the object's pointer. (Implementing `isEqual:` on top of `hash` would be a *really bad* idea, because two objects can be inequal and have the same hash. That's called a hash collision.)

Comment: If you want your objects to have a different idea of equality, you would override **both** `isEqual:` and `hash`. For more information, see the documentation of `isEqual:`: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:

Comment: Where do you ( @Peter Hosey ) see in the documentation that NSObject isEqual: behavior is to compare references? I don't see it anywhere described :/

Comment: @thibaultd: The documentation doesn't specifically say how the NSObject class implements isEqual:; on the other hand, that's pretty much the only way it can work in a class with nothing else distinctive about it. You can verify it yourself by experiment, and you can make a unit test if you worry that Apple may make -[NSObject isEqual:] work differently someday.

Comment: I know all that but I'm only regretting it's not referenced in the doc :(
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4):

The == tells you if two pointers are pointing to the same object. `isEqual` tells you if the contents of two objects are the same (but not necessarily the actual same object). A little confusing.

Try this code to understand it better:

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
NSString *bString = aString;
NSString *cString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];

if (aString == bString)
    NSLog(@"CHECK 1");

if (bString == cString)
    NSLog(@"CHECK 2");

if ([aString isEqual:bString])
    NSLog(@"CHECK 3");

if ([bString isEqual:cString])
    NSLog(@"CHECK 4");

// Look at the pointers:
NSLog(@"%p", aString);
NSLog(@"%p", bString);
NSLog(@"%p", cString);
```

Comment: You should use `%p`, not `%i`, for pointers. Printing them in hex helps reveal alignment problems because all common alignment boundaries are powers of 2 and therefore either factors or multiples of 16 (0x10); moreover, a pointer may be bigger than an `int`, so an `int` formatter may lop off part of the address and/or shift it into subsequent formatters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't know about %p.

Answer (score 1):

`[objectA isEqual:objectB]` is usually a good choice. Note that some classes may have more specialized equality functions. (`isEqualToString:` et.al.) These generally test not if they are the same object, but if the objects are equal, which is a distinct concept. (Two string objects can be equal, even if they don't have the same memory address.)

Answer (score 1):

The two other answers correctly answer the question in your title. The correct answer to the completely different question in your body text, however, is: yes, the == operator is correct for testing whether two *variables* refer to the same *object*.

Comment: I answered that in the first paragraph of my (revised as of an hour ago) answer.