# Is it good form to always use isEqual: in Objective-C for object comparison?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I know that `==` will often work for object comparison, in cases where you are comparing variables that point to the same object. Even in these cases, however, I think `isEqual:` always works.

Is it better to try and use `==` when you think you are comparing pointers, or should you always use `isEqual:` when not comparing primitives?

I tend to think that by always using `isEqual:`, you can more easily tell if the code is buggy at a glance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319247/how-to-compare-if-two-objects-are-really-the-same-object

Comment: You should use `isEqual:` and not `==` *unless you are explicitly trying to test pointer equality*.  If you want object equality, use `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 11):

Using `==`, as you said will compare the pointers. Using this, you know if the two objects are  the same instance.

**By using `isEqual:` you compare their values.**

Two distinct NSString can contain the same text: `Hello World!`. Their address will be different (*two distinct objects*) but their value will be the same.

In this case `==` will return `NO` and `isEqual:` should return `YES`.

**Example:**

```
NSString* str1 = @"Hello World!";
NSString* str2 = [@"Hello " stringByAppendingString:@"World!"];

if (str1 == str2)
{
    NSLog(@"str1 == str2");
}

if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
{
    NSLog(@"str1 is equal to str2");
}
```

**Will only output:**

> 2013-04-04 21:04:18.365 Test[7310:303] str1 is equal to str2

**Notes:**

I didn't use:

```
NSString* str1 = @"Hello World!";
NSString* str2 = @"Hello World!";
```

because the compiler generates a single object for the literal. In this case, both equalities (`==` and `isEqual:`) would have been satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an important distinction between the two.

Say you measure the length of the left and right wall of a house:
left wall length = 5 meter, right wall length = 5 meter

isEqual would tell you that both measurements amount to the same distance (5m)

== would tell you that you did not just measure the same wall twice.

I Hope this makes sense

Comment: Elaborating on this: isEqual therefore is not a sign of bugfree code. == should be used whenever you have the chance since it is more efficient than isEqual.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps this was a badly phrased question, because you seem to be the only one who knows what I was asking!

Comment: No, you should not use `==` "whenever you have the chance since it is more efficient than isEqual:".  That'll break in odd places and may break over time.  Consider `NSNumber`; `[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]` returns a singleon on most platforms/runtimes.  But `42` only does on some platforms.   Your use of `==` for `NSNumber` would lead to different behaviors on different platforms and, even, different behaviors across different OS releases.

Comment: In accepting this answer, I wasn't paying attention to the comment about speed. What I liked was his data structure example, which led me to see why you might carefully consider whether you are doing pointer or object value comparison, rather than just always using isEquals for objects.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson Right -- it was almost a good analogy, but it breaks down in the real code.  If you were to store two measurements of "5" in two instances of `NSNumber`, `==` would say they are equal because `NSNumber` returns the same object always for the an `NSNumber` that contains 5.   Pointer equality *can only be used to determine if two objects are different allocations*.  Two objects that are different allocations -- have different addresses in memory -- may or may not be equal and only `isEqual:` can be used to determine that.

Comment: Thanks @bbum, that's really interesting.

Comment: @bbum "Whenever you have the chance" should be read as "when you know you're looking for the exact same instance". I agree that it would be bad coding to make use of the behaviour that apparently resides in NSNumber (e.g. you should not rely on [NSNumber numberWithInt:3+2] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:5])