# NSManagedObject Number Comparison Failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I'm in the process of bringing an iOS app up to date - it has not had much attention since iOS 7.

I am finding that the following comparison:

```
[selectedFile valueForKey:@"canTransferToExternalApp"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

returns false when the value returned by `[selectedFile valueForKey:@"canTransferToExternalApp"]` is 1.  In the past this returned true.  What has changed?

Comment: "selectedFile" is Dictionary right?

Comment: selectedFile is an NSManagedObject

Comment: is whole code in if() condition?

Comment: The entire line of code looks like:  latestVersionDownloadedLabel.text = ([selectedFile valueForKey:@"latestVersionDownloaded"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) ? @"Yes" : @"No";

Comment: either you have to conver  NSManagedObj to NSDictionary

Answer (score 2):

You need to avoid using the equal operators for NSObjects, for reference someone answering a comparison related question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319280/933887

The issue here is you are comparing the memory addresses, not the values of the obejcts. You can read more here about Object comparison: [Introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW61)

In summary, the following would be a good solution:

```
[[selectedFile valueForKey:@"canTransferToExternalApp"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]
```

You could use `isEqualToNumber:` but you would need to ensure that you are comparing NSNumbers and not anything else. So to be safe, I recommend sticking with `isEqual:`

Comment: OK - so that works.  But why did it work in the past and is now broken?  I've probably got a lot of code like this - if it is wrong - fair enough - but why did it ever work?

Comment: It seems to work flawlessly for me when using positives, but when using negative numbers it tends to fail. In any case it seems it's better and more solid approach to use a comparison function when interacting with objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's worked

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[selectedFile[@"canTransferToExternalApp"]]] isEqualToNumber [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

**try** using same comparision either both in `int` or `NSString`

if **NSManagedObjects** not compare value directly then first convert `NSManagedObjects` to `NSDictionary`.....
for Example:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[selectedFile entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    NSDictionary *dict = [myObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];

    [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dict[@"canTransferToExternalApp"]]] isEqualToNumber [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

Comment: Converting the NSManagedObject to a dictionary did not help.